# How to fill in a status evolution two entry table with pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Python / Pandas.
I merged two tables in a DataFrame called "merged_risks", it has two columns called 'Status_N-1' and 'Status'.

**Goal** :

The goal is to count the number of status that evolved from a status (row) to an other (column) and to fill in a table with the result.

It should look like this :

[image]

So far, I did this but I am not sure if there is a better solution :

```py
    # Generate a table that shows risk status evolution
    status_comparison = merged_risks[['Status_N-1', 'Status']]
    
    # Get unique status values
    unique_values_workflow = merged_risks.Status.unique()
    d = {}
    for value in unique_values_workflow:
        d[value] = None
    
    # Add unique values as rows
    workflow_evolution = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
    
    # Add unique values as columns
    for value in unique_values_workflow:
        workflow_evolution[value] = None
```

And the result looks like this :

[image]

Do you know how to end this table?

Or maybe the pivot table is the answer to my problem?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution with groupby:

```
# Risks that didn't exist before are 'New'
merged_risks['Status_N-1'].fillna('New', inplace=True)
# Create a DataFrame that calculates size of each workflow status / status N-1
workflow_evolution = merged_risks.groupby(['Status_N-1', 'Status'])['Created'].size()
# Change rows order
workflow_evolution = workflow_evolution.reindex(['New', 'Identified', 'Analyzed', 'Waiting for decision', 'In Treatment', 'Handled', 'Canceled'], level='Status_N-1').unstack()
# Change columns order
workflow_evolution = workflow_evolution[['Identified', 'Analyzed', 'Waiting for decision', 'In Treatment', 'Handled', 'Canceled']].fillna(0).astype(int)
```